# How many average rolls to get 6 full glasses

Tags: probability, statistics

Ok so I am working on a problem and I don't have the solution to it, so I was wondering if anyone could help me out. Basically there are $6$ empty glasses. Lets say you have a $4$ sided dice (I know that's stupid, but I need an equal chance of rolling numbers $1$ through $4$) and each time you roll a number you fill the corresponding glass. If you roll a glass that is already filled, then you roll a second time and add up both numbers and then see if you can fill an empty glass. What is the average number of rolls it would take to get all $6$ glasses filled? I've been working on it, and I am getting about $18.9$ but I am not confident in my work.

Comment: How did you arrive at the answer $18.9$?

Comment: Nothing stupid about a [four-sided die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-sided_die)...

Comment: If you find the four-sided die a little stupid, you can perhaps roll a twelve-sided die, which may be smarter, and take the result modulo $4$. :-P

Comment: @BrianTung I like that method better :-).

Comment: What do you mean by add up both the numbers?? I guess you are taking modulo 6 after it??